# Algebraic extension of perfect field in which every polynomial has a root is algebraically closed

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a perfect field, i.e. every irreducible polynomial over $F$ has distinct roots in the algebraic closure of $F$. Suppose that $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ with the property that every non-constant $p(X) \in F[X]$ has a root in $K$.

I want to show that $K$ is algebraically closed, i.e. that $K = \overline{F}$, the algebraic closure of $F$.

If $K$ were a normal extension of $F$, this would follow immediately: Let $\alpha \in \overline{F}$ and $m(X)\in F[X]$ its minimal polynomial. By our assumption, $m(X)$ has at least one zero in $K$. Since $K$ is a normal extension of $F$, it thus contains all other roots of $m(X)$ including $\alpha$.

I don't have an idea as to how to show that $K$ is a normal extension.

Comment: Do you mean $p(X)\in K[X]$?  Or "has a root in $K$"?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The latter was meant.

Comment: Is the assumption that $F$ is perfect actually necessary? Do you know of an example where the conclusion fails without this assumption? (this is slightly off topic, but I'm curious)

Comment: I don't know of an example to show that the assumption that $F$ is perfect is necessary, and I think it would be hard to construct. For a non-perfect field we would have to take something like $F = \mathbb{F}_p(t)$ and construct $K$ by adjoining only certain roots of irreducible polynomials in $F$.

Comment: I think the proof of lemma 1 [here](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/algebraicclosure.pdf) should do the trick. Note that the perfect assumption on $F$ is not required.

Comment: Yes, that one works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the primitive element theorem.  For any $f\in F[x]$, let $L$ be a splitting field of $f$.  Then $L$ is finite over $F$ and separable (since $F$ is perfect), so it has a primitive element $\beta$.  We then see that $f$ splits over any extension of $F$ that has a root of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$.  In particular, $f$ splits over $K$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know, the condition that $F$ is perfect is unnecessary: if $F$ is an arbitrary field and $K/F$ is an algebraic extension such that each nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ has a root in $K$ (or, equivalently, each irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ has a root in $K$) then $K$ is algebraically closed. This is a theorem of Robert Gilmer. See [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2315743?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) or Theorem 2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/algclosure.pdf).